# How do I create this HTML5 button with an icon with rails form helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is the output I desire:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-search btn-primary">
  <i class="icon icon-search"></i> Find Your Apartment
</button>
```

If I were doing this for a link, instead of a button, I would probably do something like this:

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  <i class="icon icon-search"></i> Find Your Apartment
<% end %>
```

But given that I am using Rails form helpers, I am not quite sure how to do this with a `f.submit`.

I tried:

```
<%= f.submit, :class => "btn btn-large btn-search btn-primary" do %>
  <i class="icon icon-search"></i> Find Your Apartment
<% end %>
```

That gave me a syntax error.

Thoughts?

**Edit 1:**

For what it's worth, this doesn't give me the syntax error but it doesn't render the icon or the "Find Your Apartment" text:

```
<%= f.submit "Find Your Apartment", :class => "btn btn-large btn-search btn-primary" do %>
  <i class="icon icon-search"></i> Find Your Apartment
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use button tag

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-large btn-search btn-primary") do %>
 <i class="icon icon-search"></i> Find Your Apartment
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect...I thought I saw something like this before. Works like a gem!

Comment: in case you are using ajax and submit the form using it, then it can submit you form multiple times, then to fix it use js disable functionality with onclick event.

Comment: @vidurpunj it won't, I think if you want to using ajax for submit the form, you could use selector `id` of the button and it will triggered only when you click the button.

Comment: @rails_id, if person double click on this button, the form will get submitted 2 times.