# bootstrap icon in a submit_tag rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have this form:

```
<%= form_tag(user_pages_path(current_user), :method => "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :update, 'yes', type: "hidden"  %>
  <%= submit_tag "Update list", :class => "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

and I would like to include an icon in the button. I'm using bootstrap, so i must include this code:

```
<i class=" icon-repeat"></i>
```

¿Any idea about how to include this code in the form button?

Comment: my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14796690/1297435

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can use `button_tag` instead of `submit_tag`:

```
<%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-default") do %>
    Update list <i class="icon-repeat"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That doesn't submit my form, whereas submit_tag does. Thoughts?