# In Ruby on Rails, how to customize the submit button to use BootStrap and add a icon to it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, button

In `BootStrap`, I can use the following code to get a button with an icon.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Click Me</button>
```

Now I want to do the same thing for the submit button of a Rails form. I don't know how to do it and below is my code:

```
<h1>Create a post</h1>
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
    <p class="help-block">Please type the title of the post</>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", rows: 5 %>
    <p class="help-block">Please type the body of the post</>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

Could someone give me any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bootstrap icon in a submit\_tag rails form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999294/bootstrap-icon-in-a-submit-tag-rails-form)

Comment: Slightly different inserted content, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here: [HTML code inside buttons with simple_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858582/html-code-inside-buttons-with-simple-form)

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
 Text
<% end %>
```